# Ruby on Rails method returning nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to ruby and just testing out how to define a method with two variable inputs from the user.  Currently, it takes the values but it returns nothing.

Is there something I missing here?

```
puts "Tell me what you want to print."
      word = gets.chomp

puts "How many times do you want it printed?"
      number = gets.to_i

def print_x_times(word)
  i = 0
  while i < number
      puts(word)
    i += 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few nits here:

- You've defined a new method, but you haven't invoked it.  You're likely using something like IRB to interactively play around, but the fact remains that you've only defined that method.
- You're going to confuse yourself if you use `word` and `number` as variables inside of that method, since they're not guaranteed to be the same as the ones you've defined *outside* of it.

If you want to pass two values to the method, then you have to specify two parameters:

```
def print_x_times(word, number)
    # code
end
```

...then, you actually go about *calling* it with your variables.

```
print_x_times(word, number)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass number as an argument to the function print_x_times as you do for word

moreover, this code defines a function but doesn't call it, you should call it too

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues here...

1. You need to define the method to take two parameters, word and number.
2. Then you need to call that method with the two arguments you derived from user input.